# Why is my vuetify app bar background image not showing?

Tags: webpack, vuetify.js, nuxt.js, assets

I' trying to load a svg as the app bar background image. But it's not showing. While an image component in the app bar works, the image works when used in the template generally, as the src it does not show in the background:

```js
 <v-app-bar :clipped-left="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp" app src="~assets/background.svg">
      <img src="~assets/background.svg" />
      <template v-slot:img="{ props }">
        <v-img v-bind="props"></v-img>
      </template>

      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer" />
      <v-toolbar-title class="text-left hidden-sm-and-down">Database</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
```

results in [image: resulting app bar]

While doing

```js
 <v-app-bar :clipped-left="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp" app src="~assets/background.svg">
      <template v-slot:img="{ props }">
        <v-img v-bind="props"></v-img>
      </template>

      <v-app-bar-nav-icon @click.stop="drawer = !drawer" />
      <v-toolbar-title class="text-left hidden-sm-and-down">Database</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-app-bar>
```

results in just a blank app bar.

It seems that this is either related to svg support on app bar background, the [nuxt asset management](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/assets/) or my lack of understanding the props passing to the template element...

I have installed the @nuxtjs/svg package to support the svg display in the first place and use it as per the [installation and usage instructions](https://github.com/nuxt-community/svg-module#installation), but can't figure out the rest here.

Any support or hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just as I was about to post this, I did a final search for my problem and [found another question, where the syntax was a slightly different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60468702/vue-appbar-buttons-have-background-color) and worked, when adopted worked for my case:

Their code:

```
 <v-app-bar app>

            <v-btn v-if="$vuetify.breakpoint.smAndDown" @click="openDrawer = !openDrawer" text icon>
                <v-icon>mdi-view-headline</v-icon>
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn v-else :to="{name: 'home'}" text color="primary" class="ml-3" icon>
                <!-- Logo -->
                <img height="48"
                     :src="require('@/assets/logo.svg')"
                     alt="Manassa Logo"/>
            </v-btn>

            {{more stuff}}
        </v-app-bar>
```

--->

```
    <v-app-bar
      :clipped-left="$vuetify.breakpoint.lgAndUp"
      app
      dark
      :src="require('@/assets/images/app-bar-background.svg')"
    >
```